# json_encode unicode escape sequences cannot display in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, cordova, unicode

json_encode(array($myarray1,$myarray2))

on php contains unicode escape sequences like

```
[{
"Panelbuilder 32":
    [{
        "topic_id":"34",
        "forum_id":"6",
        "topic_title": "Panelbuilder 32",
        "topic_poster":"1",
        "topic_time":"1189740810",
        "topic_last_post_id":"124",
        "topic_last_poster_id":"1",
        "topic_last_poster_name":"vvv",
        "topic_last_post_time":"1189740810",
        "topic_last_post_subject":"Panelbuilder 32",
        "topic_last_view_time":"1436511928",
        "topic_replies":"0",
        "topic_replies_real":"0",
        "topic_views":"2463",
        "topic_attachment":"0",
        "topic_reported":"0",
        "topic_first_post_id":"124",
        "topic_first_poster_name":"vvv"
    }]
}, {
"124":
    [{
        "post_id":"124",
        "topic_id":"34",
        "forum_id":"6",
        "poster_id":"1",
        "poster_ip":"192.44.136.113",
        "post_time":"1189740810",
        "post_approved":"1",
        "post_reported":"0",
        "post_username":"vvv",
        "post_subject":"Panelbuilder 32",
        "post_text":"\u0e23\u0e03\u0e22\u0e04\u0e23\u0083\u0e23\u0081\u0e23\u0095\u0e22\u0e04\u0e23\u0087\u0e23\u0092\u0e23\u0081\u0e22\u0e0a\u0e23\u0093\u0e22\u0e19\u0e23\u0092\u0e22\u0e0d\u0e23\u0e03\u0e22\u0e19\u0e22\u0e01\u0e23\u0092\u0e23\u0083\u0e23\u0e03\u0e22\u0e0a\u0e23\u0e09\u0e23\u0e02\u0e22\u0e1b\u0e23\u0083\u0e23\u0e01\u0e22\u0e01\u0e23\u0083\u0e23\u0081 Panelbuilder 32 \u0e22\u0e02\u0e23\u008d\u0e22\u0e07  AB",
        "post_attachment":"0",
        "post_edit_time":"0",
        "topic_poster":"1",
        "topic_time":"1189740810",
        "topic_last_post_id":"124",
        "topic_last_poster_id":"1",
        "topic_last_poster_name":"vvv",
        "topic_last_post_time":"1189740810",
        "topic_last_post_subject":"Panelbuilder 32",
        "topic_last_view_time":"1436511928",
        "topic_replies":"0",
        "topic_replies_real":"0",
        "topic_views":"2463",
        "topic_attachment":"0",
        "topic_reported":"0",
        "topic_first_post_id":"124",
        "topic_first_poster_name":"vvv"
    }]
}]
```

These unicode sequences  displays in javascript like this `/ue023` (backslash converted to forward slash) and cannot displays as characters.I need to display these characters on my phonegap application. Is there any solution ?

Comment: When in javascript are you using JSON.parse();

Comment: You should post relevant code within the question rather than in external links.

Comment: yes i am using    `JSON.parse(data);`.

Comment: Try to covert your data to UTF8 which you are going to convert to json by using utf8_encode()  and then do json_encode()

Comment: Have you tried using a regular expression to convert the forward slash back into the backslash

Comment: yes i tried it on uriencoded string it gives me an error then i tried `.replace` method ,whenever i tried to display it ,it displayed another error unexpected identifier @sagar i will try it

Comment: @sagar it needs string to display i have an array it will not work it is displaying a warning

Comment: Did you escape the backslash though (remember a backslash can escape characters) if you do a replace of / with \\ (this should escape the backslash and add it as normal text

Comment: try `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`

Answer (score 0):

As you explained your using JSON.parse heres my solution:

```
var str = JSON.parse(data);
str.replace(/\//g, "\\");
```

Obviously however you get your field you will need to update the code above, e.g.

```
var new_data = str[1][124][0].post_text.replace(/\//g, "\\");
```